# regular expression which validates a relative URL

Tags: php, regex

How would I validate a string to check that it is safe for a URL. No spaces or special characters in the filename which may break the URL in gmail.

E.g: `data/Logo - free.png` would be invalid

I would only like: `"a-z", "0-9", ".", "-", "_"`

There are hundreds of questions for validating URLs on here but they all seem to check if it contains "http" which I dont need.

UPDATE with working code (from @minitech):

```
// validate filename
if (preg_match('/[^\w.-]/', basename($logo))){
    $error = true
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to check if the URL exists, just checking that there are no spaces or special characters

Comment: [what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking it right from what you listed:

```
$valid = !preg_match('/[^\w.-]/', $name);
```

You might consider just escaping it using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode), depending on the situation.

Comment: you are missing quantifier

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: No, I'm inverting the match. valid = does *not* contain things that are *not* `\w`, `.`, or `-`.

Comment: This returns true every time

Comment: @minitech correct - I had it inside a IF statement so I just needed to remove the !

Answer (score 4):

I am not a big fan of regex so I fixed PHP's internal filter_var, it seems to have a problem with relative URL's. I use this workaround:

```
function isValid($url)
{
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != '') {
        // URL has http/https/...
        return !(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false);
    }else{
        // PHP filter_var does not support relative urls, so we simulate a full URL
        // Feel free to replace example.com with any other URL, it won't matter!
        return !(filter_var('http://www.example.com/'.ltrim($url,'/'), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false);
    }
}
```

PS: Beware of the security problems in filter_var: https://d-mueller.de/blog/why-url-validation-with-filter_var-might-not-be-a-good-idea/

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to check for valid filename

```
 ^.*/[\w.-]+$
```

Comment: You're missing a starting anchor.

Comment: @minitech no need of it..just checking the filename at the end

Comment: @JohnMagnolia yes you need to put it in between `/^.*/[\w.-]+$/`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Oh, you're validating a URL. The question isn't about validating the URL, though. It's about making sure that the entire string is those characters. (At least, that's what I understood...)